# Predictive model based on Principal Components when new data has different variables

Tags: regression, pca, predictive-models, svd

I built a logistic regression model to classify a corpus of documents. The dependent variable is the type of document (eg A or B) while the dependent variables, because of dimensionality, are the first 2 components obtained by performing a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) (or a Single Value Decomposition (SVD)) on the columns (terms) of the document/term matrix.

The question is: on a new corpus of documents (and therefore a different document/terms matrix), is it methodologically correct to use the same model if the first 2 components are obtained from a different set of variables (terms)?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Should instead use the transform matrix obtained from the first dataset.

e.g.

```
transformer = PCA.fit(data_train)
PCA_train = transformer.transform(data_train)
PCA_test = transformer.transform(data_test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Kotri! 

Unfortunately, the two datasets do not have the same variables...